# How to get the X,Y,Z axis values?

Tags: iphone

Iam doing one application .In that i want to find out the x,y,z axis values.For that i used the UIAcceleroeter and his delegate method.But the problem is it was not fired when the application is in sleeping mode.So please tell me how to find out the x,yxz asix values in the sleeping mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout below tutorial.

It will help to you.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/iphone-tutorial-reading-the-accelerometer

Cheers.

Comment: This is gives the output when the application is in running stage.But i want to get that values when the application is in sleeping mode